# In android, get image id for image when captured from camera

Tags: android, camera

I have to store image id for the image captured from camera.
Through this image id I can access its thumbnails and actual image considering those image resides on device already.

I have implemented this with image picker intent, but don't know if this is possible with Camera intent. The data when printed gives null, which for me doesn't seems to be notified to Mediastore.

Any idea or solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, for a while I am implementing a workaround until I find the conventional way of doing it.

Currently my self solution is, to get a list of all the image IDs of both stages, before taking photo and after taking the photo. The new ID in new list is the ID I am looking for, when filtered with old list.

below is my code snippet.

```
private String getDiscrepantId(ArrayList<String> old_lst, ArrayList<String> new_lst){
    for(int i=0; i<old_lst.size(); i++){
        if(new_lst.contains(old_lst.get(i))){
            new_lst.remove(old_lst.get(i));
        }
    }

    return new_lst.get(0);
}
```

I hope there must be some better way to achieve this, which I believe someone will share it soon.